# php chmod not working on newly created files on Azure Web App

Tags: php, codeigniter, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am attempting to migrate an application built with CodeIgniter from a data center hosted server to run on an Azure Web App service. I've had to work through a few issues already but this one has us stumped . . .

With CodeIgniter, the CI_Log class construct method calls a function called is_really_writable in the system/core/common.php file to make sure that the log directory is writable. This function creates a file in the given folder, then attempts to execute chmod on the file to set permissions then deletes it. If it is able to complete these actions it assumes it can write to the directory.

I am getting the following error in my log files when this is called:

> ERROR - 2016-11-02 12:19:42 --> Severity: Warning  --> chmod(): No such file or directory D:\home\site\wwwroot\system\core\Common.php 92
>
> ERROR - 2016-11-02 12:19:42 --> Severity: Warning  --> unlink(application/logs/1f3202d820180a39f736f20fce790de8): No such file or directory D:\home\site\wwwroot\system\core\Common.php 93

Then my log folder has my normal log files, and a lot of garbage files like the "1f3202d820180a39f736f20fce790de8" above. It seems that this function has to be returning true sometimes because it does write a log file (which it would not do if the function were to return false).

My only ideas are:
 - It could be something to do with permissions on Azure. I find this to be unlikely because it must be successful at least a few times because the logs are getting created and written to.
 - Maybe the server is just really slow and the file is not created before attempting to chmod and then unlink. I find this to be really unlikely though because I would think that the fopen function would not return until the file was created.

I am at my wits end and just about ready to give up trying to use Azure Web App service if I can't get this working. Any ideas?

For reference, here is the code of the function in question:

```
function is_really_writable($file)
{
    // If we're on a Unix server with safe_mode off we call is_writable
    if (DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR == '/' AND @ini_get("safe_mode") != TRUE)
    {
        return is_writable($file);
    }

    // For windows servers and safe_mode "on" installations we'll actually
    // write a file then read it.  Bah...
    if (is_dir($file))
    {
        $file = rtrim($file, '/').'/'.md5(mt_rand(1,100).mt_rand(1,100));

        if (($fp = @fopen($file, FOPEN_WRITE_CREATE)) === FALSE)
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        fclose($fp);
        @chmod($file, DIR_WRITE_MODE);
        @unlink($file);
        return TRUE;
    }
    elseif ( ! is_file($file) OR ($fp = @fopen($file, FOPEN_WRITE_CREATE)) === FALSE)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    fclose($fp);
    return TRUE;
}
```

And here is the construct method of the log class that is calling it:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $config =& get_config();

    $this->_log_path = ($config['log_path'] != '') ? $config['log_path'] : APPPATH.'logs/';

    if ( ! is_dir($this->_log_path) OR ! is_really_writable($this->_log_path))
    {
        $this->_enabled = FALSE;
    }

    if (is_numeric($config['log_threshold']))
    {
        $this->_threshold = $config['log_threshold'];
    }

    if ($config['log_date_format'] != '')
    {
        $this->_date_fmt = $config['log_date_format'];
    }
}
```

Per [gary-liu-msft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4989668/gary-liu-msft) suggestion, I have done some more work to isolate this as just a problem with CodeIgniter and I am 100% sure it is just the version of CodeIgniter we are using at this point. I created a script with the same function in it and had it run thousands of time without experiencing the same behavior. I will try first updating to the latest version of CodeIgniter 2 and if that does not work we will have to try out the latest of version 3. I will update once I have a resolution for anyone else who comes to this problem.

Comment: I should also mention that this application is extremely slow (25 seconds to load page that takes 6 seconds on our current production Windows server, yes I know that is bad but I used one of the longest loading pages as a test to compare the environments). I have yet to pinpoint if the difference is due to the Database which we migrated to Azure SQL or the PHP but I have a feeling whatever is causing this sluggishness may be contributing to my above described issue.

Comment: Which CI version you are using in your scenario? Do you have any custom configurations or you are simply deploying a CI application on Azure Web Apps?

Comment: We are on 2.1.4 and there are no custom configurations to the core CodeIgniter classes in our application.

Comment: It seems that you are using an old version, now the latest stable version 3.1, has changed this function at https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Common.php#L91. And it works fine on my side. You can try to upgrade your CI version and try again.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try that out but it looks like there is a lot of work involved in moving an application from 2.1.4 to 3.1 and it doesn't appear that this function has changed from the version we're using so I don't think it will matter. I think I may just make my own simple php script to simulate the problem so I can isolate it down to the actual problem instead of looking at it as a problem with CI.  I'll report back with any findings in case anyone else comes across this issue

Answer (score 0):

`chmod` is a Linux construct, not Windows. And unless you're using the Linux preview of App Services, your web app is sitting atop Windows, and won't let you run `chmod`.

Under your app's `wwwroot`, your app has full write permission anyway.

Comment: This works fine on a windows server now, and as I mentioned it does seem to return true at least a few times because the log files are getting created. Also, chmod is a supported function on Azure Web App environment. You can use it from the command prompt in their Kudu environment.